# Lazarus - why doesn't this work with ShowModal?

Tags: modal-dialog, lazarus

I have two forms in Lazarus. one is frmMain and the other is frmSub1. both have a text box.

The following code works. i.e., on clicking a button on frmMain, the value

```
procedure TfrmMain.cmdShowClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmSub1.Show  ;
  frmSub1.txtAns.text := txtMark.Text;
end;
```

But when I replace **.Show** with **.ShowModal**, it shows the form but **frmSub1.txtAns** is blank.

Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `ShowModal` is **blocking** call, ie the line `frmSub1.txtAns.text := txtMark.Text;` wont execute until it returns. You have to switch the order of statements, following should work as you expect:

```
procedure TfrmMain.cmdShowClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmSub1.txtAns.text := txtMark.Text;
  frmSub1.ShowModal;
end;
```